# Converting own firebase class from Javascript to Typescript gives me errors

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to convert my previous Javascript firebase class to Typescript but I'm getting the following warning/error: Property 'auth' does not exist on type 'Firebase'.

I tried looking for the problem but can't find a clear answer. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config)

    this.auth = app.auth()
  }

  doSignInWithGoogle = () => this.auth.signInWithPopup(this.googleProvider)
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase may be configured in Typescript as shown below. The class properties `app` and `auth` may be public or private depending on your intended design.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'


class Firebase {
  app: firebase.app.App
  auth: firebase.auth.Auth

  constructor() {
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App
    this.app = firebase.initializeApp(config)
    this.auth = firebase.auth(this.app)
  }

  public signInWithGooglePopup(): Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential> {
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#sign-inwith-popup
    return this.auth.signInWithPopup(this.googleProvider)
  }
}
```

Comment: ＠christopher peisert This works perfectly! thank you!  is it also good practice to annotate the following like this:   doSignInWithGoogle = (): Record<string, object> ??

Comment: @Kyle See updated example with method `signInWithGooglePopup`. With Typescript, the more you leverage types, the more the Typescript compiler can help catch errors.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I'm new to typescript :) Since It's actually returning a promise I think it should be like this: doSignInWithGoogle = (): Promise<object>

Comment: @Kyle See update with the method returning type `Promise<firebase.auth.UserCredential>`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the auth property in the class as `private auth;`.

Your code should look like:

```
class Firebase {

    private auth;

    constructor() {
        app.initializeApp(config)

        this.auth = app.auth()
    }

    doSignInWithGoogle = () => this.auth.signInWithPopup(this.googleProvider)
}
```

Comment: Great that works thanks! but what type do I put? private auth: Any?

Comment: Use this: firebase.auth.Auth.